# Unit Testing: Reasons a ViewResult would be null, and why is it worth testing for?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

Other questions that mention null ViewResults actually seem to be referring to null Models (something I definitely *do* plan to test for). I am brand new to testing. Just started my first project using TDD today. Several of the resources I found, and even the stock testing code for a new MVC project, show testing the ViewResult for null:

```
// Stock code
[TestMethod]
public void Index()
{
    // Arrange
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    // Act
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I am wondering why this is necessary. Given my limited experience, I can think of only 2 reasons why the ViewResult would be null:

Reason 1: You return the wrong type, like a JsonResult or something - which could be done if the method returns a general ActionResult. I could see this being a legit reason, but I am not sure it's a requirement my method needs to return a ViewResult specifically. In fact, maybe I want it to be easily changeable down the road.

Reason 2: You explicitly return null. But in the real world, why would you do that?

Can someone give other examples of when the ViewResult would be null, and explain why (or why not) it's important to test for? My experience is limited as I said, so there is liable to be something I am not seeing - that's why I am asking.

**EDIT**
Apologies if I formatted my question poorly. Let me clarify: I understand it's bad if it's null, and understand the value in testing for null *if nulls are possible/likely*. I am more concerned with A. *how/why* would it be null in the first place, and B. whether these reasons are legit reasons that would add value to test, or whether they're edge cases unlikely to ever happen in the real world. 

 **Did my Reason 1 and Reason 2 cover all of the scenarios? If not, what others are there? If they are edge cases, highly unlikely to happen, do you still test for them?**

Comment: `understand the value in testing for null if nulls are possible/likely` - So, you are saying if null is unlikely, one should not have a `null check` test case? Think about it this way - the `null check` test case itself _conveys_ that a `null` here is unlikely.

Comment: @YK1 Are you saying that a test indicates an unlikely mistake? But would you not also test for *likely*, easy-to-make mistakes? And wouldn't those tests add more value than a test for a mistake no developer is liable to make to begin with? Your interpretation seems to be that if anything is nullable that shouldn't be, test to make sure it isn't, period - and that may well be the correct way to do things, not disputing that, I just was under the impression testing for highly unlikely mistakes is overdoing things/"testing for the sake of testing" instead of adding real value.

Comment: This is why my question focused on how _likely of a mistake_ it was, and why what I was really looking for were scenarios that'd cause it. The consensus seems to be, however, that my impression was incorrect, and that you should test every scenario no matter how unlikely it is.

Comment: `But would you not also test for likely, easy-to-make mistakes?`. Sure we should test for those. `Your interpretation seems to be that if anything is nullable that shouldn't be, test to make sure it isn't, period` - this interpretation is **only** for this _particular_ test case in question, which as you mentioned is also part of default stock test code. If you have likely nulls, then you will not have this test case, you'll have different test case which accommodate situations where null is likely.

Comment: `testing for highly unlikely mistakes is overdoing things`- In general I'd say other way round. The more you test for highly unlikely cases, better fortified is your test suite. In your particular case, you'd say the developer has to be really dumb to return a null view - very highly unlikely. So, are other situations like hardware failure, network delays, scalabiliy - and truly this stuff is hard to test with unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of tests are twofold.  When doing test driven development, they drive your code development.  You write a test that asserts the returned view is not null.  This test fails at first, until you write code that satisfies it.

The second step is to give warning in the even that the code changes, and does return null.

2 years from now, you might alter the method to add more complex logic that accidentally causes a null return.  You want to catch that right away.

Comment: While I am still wondering specific scenarios that would cause a null return, your answer came the closest because you mentioned needing the check for the first step of TDD - and I was forgetting this part since it was a stock generated method/unit test that I was then modifying (Home/Index, so the code already existed to make the test pass).

Comment: @user2607389 - It's hard to say what the scenario would be.  But an example I've had is where I would lookup a view to return based on some other value.  In theory, there should always be a case where a view is returned, but my code could have a bug in it...  The point is, the returned view is a reference type.. it's possible for it to be Null, therefore it should be checked in case it ever changes.

Comment: Thanks for the example - that does indeed seem a very real possibility I hadn't thought of. And regardless, lesson learned to check all nullable types, always.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone give other examples of when the ViewResult would be null

It should *never* be `null` and that is what this test case validates. If developer introduces a bug in the controller code by somehow returning `null`, this test case would fail and lots of lives saved before buggy code goes to production.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every test we write against controller actions makes sure the ActionResult that gets returned (be it a ViewResult, RedirectResult, etc) checks to make sure it is not null. That's less to do with making sure it's not null and more to do with subsequent asserts. For example, let's say your test looked like this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index()
{
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull( result.Model );
}
```

If, somehow, the result was null when you tried to dereference it to get to the Model property a NullReferenceException would be thrown. Your test would fail, but it would fail with an exception being thrown. Now the developer has to figure out what reference was null. For us it's really just a way of making sure you don't get a hard-to-debug failure later in your code when you try to use the result that came back.